# Not identifying read only checkbox is checked in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have parameters with edit and save option.For instance in below table

Parametername   Type1             Type2             Type3

Test           rdb(checkBox)     rdb(checkBox)   rdb(checkBox)  Edit(Button)

If i click edit button, row will be enabled and i need to select any one type check box and save the type.While saving the type i assigned checkbox value as rdb='t'.This 't' will save it in data base.Now i am facing issue with this.Whenever selecting checkbox,value is going as null.Below code i am using.

Mange_Page.html.erb

```
<script>
    $('.editoidbtn').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var oid = $this.closest('tr').find('td:first-child').filter(function() {
            return $(this).find('.editoidbtn').length === 0;
        });
        var oidName = $this.closest('tr').find('td:first-child').next().filter(function() {
            return $(this).find('.editoidbtn').length === 0;
        });
        var expected = $this.closest('tr').find('td:first-child').next().next().filter(function() {
            return $(this).find('.editoidbtn').length === 0;
        });

        if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
            $this.html('Save');
            oid.attr('contenteditable', true);
            oidName.attr('contenteditable', true);
            expected.attr('contenteditable', true);
            $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='rd_b']").attr('disabled', false);
            $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='rd_v']").attr('disabled', false);
            $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='rd_c']").attr('disabled', false);
            $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='review']").attr('disabled', false);
            $this.closest('tr').css('border',  " solid skyblue");
        }
        else {

            if ($this.html() === 'Save') {
                saveRows($this);
                $this.html('Edit');
                oid.attr('contenteditable', false);
                oidName.attr('contenteditable', false);
                expected.attr('contenteditable', false);
                $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='rd_b']").attr('disabled', true);
                $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='rd_v']").attr('disabled', true);
                $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='rd_c']").attr('disabled', true);
                $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='review']").attr('disabled', true);
                $this.closest('tr').css('border', 'none');
            }
        }
    });
```

Java script

```
function saveRows($this){

    tr181 = $('#TR_protocol').is(":visible");
    snmp = $('#SN_protocol').is(":visible");

    var values = [];
    var $row = $this.closest("tr"),
    $tds = $row.find("td");
  count = 0;
  $.each($tds, function() {
   values[count]=$(this).text();
    count++;
  });

  if(tr181){
   var parameter_name = values[0].trim();
   var expected_value = values[1].trim();
    if($row.find("input[name='rd_b']").attr('checked')){
      var rdb = 't'
     }else{
       rdb =null;
     }
    if($row.find("input[name=rd_v]").attr('checked')){
    var rdv = 't'
    }else{
     rdv =null;
    }
    if($row.find("input[name=rd_c]").attr('checked')){
      var rdc = 't'
    }else{
      rdc =null;
    }
    if($row.find("input[name=reviews]").attr('checked')){
        var review = null;
      }

    $.ajax({    
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "/configuration/update_parameter",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        parameter_name: parameter_name,
        expected_value: expected_value,
        rdb: rdb,
        rdv: rdv,
        rdc: rdc,
        review: review,
       }),
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        success: function (result) {
        if (result === 'false') {
            alert('Parameter not Updated  !!!');
            return false;
         } else {
            alert('Parameter Updated successfully  !!!');
          }
        }
     });
   }
 }
 }
```

From below part i am getting Ajax response as nil.When i click save button control is going to else part eventhough i have sleeted checkbox.It has to go with value 't'.

```
if($row.find("input[name='rd_b']").attr('checked')){
      var rdb = 't'
     }else{
       rdb =null;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is your code for checking the value if checked or not?

Have you try to used,

```
example: .find("input[name=rd_v]").is(':checked') # returns true or false
```

Comment: Thanks.But getting same nil response.Please find below ajax response.I have selected rdb checkbox.

Comment: {"parametername"=>"Test", "expected_value"=>"", "rdb"=>nil, "rdv"=>nil, "rdc"=>nil, "configuration"=>{"parametername"=>"Test",  "expected_value"=>"", "rdb"=>nil, "rdv"=>nil, "rd"c=>nil}}

Comment: it has to go value as 't' but going as nil

Comment: Thanks .I tried this way- .find("input[name=rd_v]").is(':checked',true).It is working.